# "Desktop" not showing in Navigation Pane

Tags: windows-7, navigation

**How did this happen?  How do I get it back?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right-click on the `Favorites` menu and click `Restore Favorite links`.

Comment: Yes, that works too. :-) Not sure how I missed it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply browsing to your desktop in Explorer, right-clicking *Favorites* in the sidebar on the left, and then selecting *Add current location [...]* should do the trick.

Comment: I don't see "Favorites" when I right-click on my desktop.

Comment: In the Explorer window you took a screenshot of, Favorites is listed in de sidebar. Right click that.

Comment: That isn't clear from what you wrote, sorry.

Comment: Well, if you're right-clicking your desktop, you didn't browse to it.

Comment: Awesome tip!  I can use it to add other folders!  I never knew that; thanks!!!  +100

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the Star favorites. You just search the desktop icon and drag the same to your favorites. It will appear in the list.

Answer (score -1):

**Do the followings:**

- Open windows explorer.
- Right click on favorite in left pane.
- Click restore favorite links.
- Then click on sort by name.

It's done.

Answer (score -1):

1- open my computer
2- go to left pane in your screen
3- you will get favorites on the top of left screen
4- right click on favorites and select expand 
5- now you can see your desktop icon inside the left pane.